# Excel XML Line Feeds in Fields

Tags: c#, xml, excel

I' trying to get the following string to output to a cell in Excel using the 2003 XML capabilities "Cheese\nBread" and at the moment it ignores the line break.

If I create a file with the desired effect then I get the following output

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String">Cheese&#10;Monkey</Data></Cell>
```

Okay, so I try doing...

```
text.Replace('\n',(char)10);
```

or
    text.Replace("\n","
");

To no avail, the first does nothing useful and in the second the XmlWriter simply escapes it with an & which is really helpful.

Any ideas, maybe a setting on the .NET XmlWriter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `xml:space="preserve"` on the `Data` element:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="s62"><Data ss:Type="String" xml:space="preserve">Cheese
Monkey</Data></Cell>
```

Comment: hmm on second look this didn't work for me (the words wrapped simply due to the column size which is why I thought it worked)

Comment: In that case your Excel version does not handle XML correctly, and you may have to do postprocessing of the XML text, for instance with a Regex, or by creating your own XmlTextWriter derivate which replaces the newlines with &#10; when WriteString is invoked while the writer is on a Data tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the following to my XML definition (within the "Workbook" element):

```
<Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="sMultiLine">
    <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" ss:WrapText="1"/>
  </Style>
</Styles>
```

And then, in the "Cell" element, add the appropriate matching style:

```
<Cell ss:StyleID="sMultiLine">
```

I actually added a minor XSLT adjustment so that value only showed up if it detected newlines in the content:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(.,'#10;')">
      <xsl:attribute name="ss:StyleID">sMultiLine</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:if>
```